PBI Report Builder, Repetir reporte por cada registro
no se si esto se pueda hacer pero tengo un reporte que muestra una orden de venta y sus lineas, y lo que se me pide hacer es que el reporte se genere por cada linea. Osea si el reporte tiene 5 lineas el reporte se va a repetir 5 veces. Ya he buscado pero no he encontrado nada y no tengo la menor idea si esto es posible.
Gracias
